# I deleted a branch with -d, how can I restore/recover it?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

I deleted a branch with:

```
git branch -d <branch>
```

it said:

```
 git branch -d oleg/feature/1533692217
warning: deleting branch 'oleg/feature/1533692217' that has been merged to
         'refs/remotes/origin/oleg/feature/1533692217', but not yet merged to HEAD.
Deleted branch oleg/feature/1533692217 (was f7a4a13).
```

I think I know what that means, how can I restore branch with name:

```
oleg/feature/1533692217
```

is there a way to restore the branch without checking it out?

**Note** that I squashed the feature branch that I deleted, when I merged it with the integration branch, and that's one reason why the warning message may have appeared..maybe git doesn't handle that case?

Comment: Why does it need to be without checking it out? (You can, but checking it out is the easiest way…)

Comment: cause my index/worktree is dirty and I don't want to clean it up first

Answer (score 5):

I would do

```
git branch oleg/feature/1533692217 f7a4a13
```

This has the same effect as Ry-'s answer -- it recreates the deleted branch, pointing to the same tip commit that it was pointing to before it was deleted -- except that it doesn't rely on understanding what's going on with the `origin/oleg/feature/1533692217` branch.

Answer (score 1):

```
git branch oleg/feature/1533692217 origin/oleg/feature/1533692217
```

Comment: thanks, can you explain what that is doing? also, can you comment on whether squashing the branch might be the reason why the warning occurred?

Comment: @MrCholo: If you were on the integration branch when running `git branch -d`, yes, a merge that wasn’t actually a merge (e.g. a “squash merge”) would be the cause of that message. `git branch x y` creates a branch called *x* from the revision identified by *y*. Read `git help branch`, second form.